# Arrows along path in TikZ flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Instead of drawing each arrow separately, I am interested in a quicker way to draw arrows along a path in a flowchart.

Let's look at some code first, MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,quotes,fit,calc}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [%
rectangle,
rounded corners,
%   minimum width=3cm,
%   max width=2cm,
minimum height=1cm,
text centered,
text width=2cm,
line width=1pt,
draw=DarkBlue,
fill=DarkBlue!30
]

\tikzstyle{process} = [%
rectangle,
%   minimum width=3cm,
%   max width=2cm,
minimum height=1cm,
text centered,
text width=2cm,
draw=orange,
fill=orange!30
]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [%
thick,
->,
>=stealth,
]

\tikzstyle{mainarrow} = [%
ultra thick,
->,
>=stealth,
]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (mycenternode) [startstop]                      {Isgrind};
    \node (mynorthnode)  [process, above=of mycenternode] {Sami};
    \node (mysouthnode)  [process, below=of mycenternode] {Romrike};
    \node (mywestnode)   [process, left=of mycenternode]  {Rykinmaa};
    \node (myeastnode)   [process, right=of mycenternode] {Lukinsola};

    \draw [mainarrow] (mynorthnode)  --                           (mycenternode);
    \draw [mainarrow] (mycenternode) -- node[anchor=west]  {kuf}  (mysouthnode);
    \draw [arrow] (mywestnode)   -- node[anchor=south] {ders} (mycenternode);
    \draw [arrow] (mycenternode)  -- node[anchor=south]  {olan} (myeastnode);

    \path [arrow] (mywestnode) |- node[anchor=south] {punrot} (mynorthnode) -| (myeastnode);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Instead of having to say

```
    \draw [mainarrow] (mynorthnode)  -- (mycenternode);
    \draw [mainarrow] (mycenternode) -- node[anchor=west]  {kuf}  (mysouthnode);
    \draw [arrow] (mywestnode) -- node[anchor=south] {ders} (mycenternode);
    \draw [arrow] (mycenternode) -- node[anchor=south]  {olan} (myeastnode);
```

I wonder how to shorten that to something like

```
\path [mainarrow] (mynorthnode)  -- (mycenternode) -- node[anchor=west]  {kuf}  (mysouthnode);
\path [arrow] (mywestnode) -- node[anchor=south] {ders} (mycenternode) -- node[anchor=south]  {olan} (myeastnode);
```

EXTRA:
In the last few lines, you can discern a `\path`. I don't really understand why it's not drawing anything.

Comment: `\path` and `\draw` are two different things. `\path` does not draw unless you say `\path[draw,...]`. Also consider using `\tikzset{blabla/.style={...}` instead of `\tikzstyle{blabla}=[...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `edge` operation. You were already loading quotes (and several packages that you do not use), which allows you to attach the labels to the arrows with a shorter syntax. The relevant piece of your code can thus be condensed to

```
\draw  (mynorthnode)  edge[mainarrow]  (mycenternode) 
    (mycenternode) edge[mainarrow,"kuf"]    (mysouthnode)
     (mywestnode)   edge[arrow,"ders"] (mycenternode)
  (mycenternode)  edge[arrow,"olan"] (myeastnode);
```

Note that `\path` alone does not draw. This is the reason why the lines do not appear. I added two styles for edges with corners, `BR` and `BL`, such that the path in the end can be drawn with edges as well,

```
\draw [arrow] (mywestnode)  edge[BR,"punrot"] (mynorthnode)
 (mynorthnode) edge[BL] (myeastnode);
```

This is the MWE with some unused libraries removed and `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,quotes}

\tikzset{startstop/.style={
rectangle,
rounded corners,
%   minimum width=3cm,
%   max width=2cm,
minimum height=1cm,
text centered,
text width=2cm,
line width=1pt,
draw=DarkBlue,
fill=DarkBlue!30},
process/.style={%
rectangle,
%   minimum width=3cm,
%   max width=2cm,
minimum height=1cm,
text centered,
text width=2cm,
draw=orange,
fill=orange!30},
arrow/.style={%
thick,
->,
>=stealth,
},
mainarrow/.style={%
ultra thick,
->,
>=stealth,
},
BR/.style={ to path={|- (\tikztotarget)  \tikztonodes}},
BL/.style={ to path={-| (\tikztotarget)  \tikztonodes}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (mycenternode) [startstop]                      {Isgrind};
    \node (mynorthnode)  [process, above=of mycenternode] {Sami};
    \node (mysouthnode)  [process, below=of mycenternode] {Romrike};
    \node (mywestnode)   [process, left=of mycenternode]  {Rykinmaa};
    \node (myeastnode)   [process, right=of mycenternode] {Lukinsola};

    \draw  (mynorthnode)  edge[mainarrow]  (mycenternode) 
        (mycenternode) edge[mainarrow,"kuf"]    (mysouthnode)
         (mywestnode)   edge[arrow,"ders"] (mycenternode)
      (mycenternode)  edge[arrow,"olan"] (myeastnode);

    \draw [arrow] (mywestnode)  edge[BR,"punrot"] (mynorthnode)
     (mynorthnode) edge[BL] (myeastnode);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will only get one arrow tip when you use `--`, but if you use `edge` instead, you'll get an arrow tip for each segment, as `edge` inserts a separate path (I think). Anyways, you can actually make do with specifying the center node only once:

```
\path [mainarrow]  (mycenternode) edge[<-]                          (mynorthnode)
                                  edge           node[right] {kuf}  (mysouthnode)
                                  edge[arrow,<-] node[above] {ders} (mywestnode)
                                  edge[arrow]    node[above] {olan} (myeastnode);
```

Comment: By using the `quotes` syntax marmot demonstrates in his answer, you can shorten this a bit more.

Comment: I must deduce, that, as soon as the diagram is not a cross any more, but a longer chain, I won't get around repeating the nodes in the chain. This being the case, I take from both of your answers that a chain without repetition of the nodes involved is not possible. Then marmot's answer becomes more in-depth.